# VoIP - Send number and initiate call

Tags: voip, telephony, avaya

I can connect to a VOIP phone, on my web app I have a list of telephone numbers. When I click on a telephone number, how can I send a number to this VoIP phone and initiate a call from that handset?

Webapp is on an intranet and is privately used only.

Phone model: Avaya 1210 and Avaya 1220

Is this possible?

Comment: What's your phone system or vendor?

Comment: Avaya 1210 and Avaya 1220

Comment: It's your desk phone model number, I asked about your phone system, that phone connected to the central system(PBX).

Comment: I think its the CS1K provided by same company

Comment: OK, CS1000 Avaya, and Avaya 1220 IP desk phone,  Could you explain how you can connect to your phone now? Do you mean connecting through the web settings page? if yes, it's not possible with this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For click to call, call process monitoring on Avaya phone system, you should use Avaya CTI. It helps you to make a Windows application or web application to connect your CS1000 phone system and dial a phone number.

When you click on the phone number on your web app, your web app should connect to Avaya CTI API and send dial command with parameters like phone number and extension number.
For more information read the following documents:

https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/communication_server_1000/interfaces/sip_cti/overview/index.gsp

https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/communication_server_1000/releases/7_6/index.gsp

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. We'll have to look into this API and see what sort of language we can use to implement this.